# Побайтовое чтение WAV файла на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav

Как можно прочитать WAV файл по байтам или хотя бы по фреймам для последовательной обработки на Python 3?

Comment: вероятно вас `bytestring = open('audio.wav', 'rb').read()` не интересует. Посмотрите на связанный вопрос: [Reading *.wav files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2060628/4279) и уточните ваш вопрос, если необходимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обработки скорее всего проще будет воспользоваться scipy, там есть готовая функция [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) для чтения wav-файлов.